# Synchronize data with filter using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I have web application with Sql Server as back-end and windows application with Sql Compact as back-end.

I have to synchronize tables data between this two application two way.

It is working well using Sync framework toolkit. I applied solution exactly same as example given in below link.

http://www.systenics.com/blog/sync-sql-server-2012-data-with-sql-ce-35-sp2-over-the-internet-using-wcf-services-using-ms-sync-framework-v21/?tag=Sync+Framework+v2.1

I have to synchronize with filter by particular column of table (UserID).

Please help me to synchronize tables with filter between web and windows.

Comment: what issues are you encountering? filtering is supported out of the box and you can find how to do exactly in the documentation walkthrough.

Answer (score 1):

filtering is supported out of the box. see this walkthroughs on the documenation:

[Walkthrough: Defining Filtered Scope and Provisioning Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928521.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Provisioning a Client with Filtered Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928732.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Executing Synchronization for the Filtered Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928769.aspx)

Comment: Can you help me with filtering using given example link in question please?